# holomorphic function on $R=\{z\in \mathbb{C} \mid |z|<1\}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $A$ be a set of all injective and holomorphic functions on $R=\{z\in \mathbb{C} \mid |z|<1\}$
with $f(0)=0,f'(0)=1$ then

(1) for any $a\in R$ prove that function $g(z)=\frac{z}{(1-az)^2}$ is in $A$
also show that there exists function $G(z)$ in $A$ satisfying $(G(z))^2=g(z^2)$ for all $z\in R$

(2) for any $f \in A$ show that there exist $F\in A$ satisfy $(F(z))^2=f(z^2)$ for all $z\in R$

For (1) I substitute $z=a+bi$ and use Cauchy-Riemann to show that $g(z)$ is holmorphic (with some brute force) then it is easy to show $g(0)=0$, $g'(0)=1$ and injectivity. For $G(z)$, I define it to be $\frac{z}{(1-az^2)}$ but am too exhausted to use Cauchy-Riemann. Are there any more appropriate ways to show this?

(2) Since $f$ is holomorphic and $f(0)=0$, $f'(0)=1$ we can express $f$ using Taylor series
$$f(z)=z+\frac{f''(0)z^2}{2!}+ \cdots$$ but have no idea how to use injectivity and find $F(z)$.
(already tried by comparing coefficient of $f(z^2)=F(z)$ to find $F(z)$ but cannot show the injectivity of $F$)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

For $(2)$: $f(0)=0$ implies that $f(z)=z^mh(z)$ for some $m\geq 1$ and holomorphic function $h$ with $h(0)\neq 0$, and the condition $f'(0)=1$ implies that $m=1$ (order of multiplicity of $0$).since $f$ is injective we have that $f(z)\neq 0$ for all $z\neq 0$, hence $h(z)\neq 0$ for all $z\in R$.

because $h$ not vanish in $R$ (simply connected domain) then there exists a holomorphic function $h_1$ on $R$ such that $h(z)=e^{h_1(z)}$ for all $z\in R$. hence $f(z)=ze^{h_1(z)}$ for all $z\in R$. but $f'(0)=1$ implies that $e^{h_1(0)}=1$ then $h_1(0)=2ik\pi$ for some $k\in \Bbb Z$, now take $h_2(z)=h_1(z)-2ik\pi$ that is $h_2(0)=0$ and $f(z)=ze^{h_2(z)}$.

For all $z\in R$, we have $f(z^2)=z^2e^{h_2(z^2)}=F(z)^2$ where $F(z)=ze^{\frac{1}{2}h_2(z^2)}$ , $z\in R$.

It is easy to show that $F(0)=0$ and $F'(0)=1$.

For the injectivity of $F$: Let $a,b$ in $R$ such that $F(a)=F(b)$ hence $f(a^2)=F(a)^2=F(b)^2=f(b^2)$, by the injectivity of $f$ we get $a^2=b^2$; if $a=b$ (there is no thing to show), if $a=-b$ then $F(a)=ae^{\frac{1}{2}h_2(a^2)}=F(-a)=-ae^{\frac{1}{2}h_2(a^2)}$ this implies that $a=-a$ hence $a=b=0$.